# R: Aggregating data between two dates without a loop

Tags: r, aggregate

I have two dataframes, one with trade data (which can occur in any interval of time) and another which breaks time up into hourly intervals. Both contain a column with the date and time. There can be several trades within an hour and I would like to aggregate all the trades in an hour time period in the trades dataframe into one row in the hourly dataframe.

For example:
Trade Table

```
       Time                  Amount  
2014-09-10 13:01:01            10  
2014-09-10 13:05:13            20
2014-09-10 13:59:40             1  
2014-09-10 14:30:45             2  
2014-09-10 14:50:00            30
```

I would like to aggregate this in the hourly table as follows:

```
        Time         Amount
2014-09-10 14:00:00   31   (i.e. 10+20+1)
2014-09-10 15:00:00   32   (i.e. 2+30)
```

Above, all trade between `2014-09-10 13:00:00` and `2014-09-10 14:00:00` have been aggregated and placed under `2014-09-10 14:00:00`
My current code looks as follows:

```
for (m in 2:nrow(hourlyData))
{
      hourlyData[m,2] = sum(as.numeric(tradeData[intersect(which(tradeData[,1] < hourlyData[m,1]),
        which(tradeData[,1] >= hourlyData[m-1,1])),2])) #Get P&L aggregated by date        
}
```

Which works, but is very slow.

Does anyone have advice on how I could do this without a for loop?

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>%
      group_by(Time=as.POSIXct(Time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H")+3600) %>%
      summarise(Amount=sum(Amount))
```

gives the output

```
  #                 Time Amount
  #1 2014-09-10 14 00:00     31
  #2 2014-09-10 15 00:00     32
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Time = c("2014-09-10 13:01:01", "2014-09-10 13:05:13", 
"2014-09-10 13:59:40", "2014-09-10 14:30:45", "2014-09-10 14:50:00"
), Amount = c(10L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 30L)), .Names = c("Time", "Amount"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: @David Arenburg Thanks.  Actually, I was trying for a base solution first. Then, I changed mind to `dplyr`.  Perhaps I don't even need to create a variable.  Just use it in the `group_by` as you have done.

Comment: @Mike It is a `pipe` operator.  It connects different statements `lhs` and `rhs` of the operator.  In the previous versions, it was `%.%`, now it changed to the current format. You can also go through this link  http://www.r-statistics.com/2014/08/simpler-r-coding-with-pipes-the-present-and-future-of-the-magrittr-package/

Comment: thanks for the response. I have a similar, but slightly different question: How would I do the aggregation (as you've done above), but then slot the results into a separate table, which contains hourly data? So, for example, the other matrix would have all 24 hours of 2014-09-10, and I would want to place the "31" above in the 2014-09-10 14:00:00 row. Would you be able to help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: @Mike please post it as a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Here's `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(Amount = sum(Amount)), 
            by = list(Time = as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H") + 3600)]
#                   Time Amount
# 1: 2014-09-10 14:00:00     31
# 2: 2014-09-10 15:00:00     32
```

---

Edit: This is how you would do it efficiently (though less) with base R

```
with(df, tapply(Amount, (as.POSIXct(Time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H") + 3600), FUN = sum))
```

Or (less efficient, but returns a data.frame)

```
with(df, aggregate(Amount, list((as.POSIXct(Time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H") + 3600)), FUN = sum))
```

Or

```
aggregate(df$Amount ~ with(df, as.POSIXct(Time, format="%Y-%m-%d %H") + 3600), FUN = sum)
```